# Should the Daily Close Limit be Higher?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, vote-to-close

I spend too much time on SO.

One result of that is that it's fairly easy for me to see questions that are duplicates of one posted a few days before - I still remember seeing that one. About half the time, I can find the duplicate quickly in a search.

Such a question should get a close vote from me with "Exact duplicate". The problem is, I can only do that 12 times a day. Between the number of obvious duplicates, and other close reasons, I run out close votes fairly early in the day.

I also see a lot of questions with only one or two close votes, even if they're obvious duplicates. I wonder if that's due to other closers having hit their daily limit?

In any case, I think the limit should be relaxed. Perhaps the limit could increase based on reputation. But 12 a day will only be enough when there are only 12 questions a day that deserve a close vote from me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was discussed quite a long time ago and I think Atwood's reasoning for keeping it that way was "eventually there will be enough users with over 3000 rep that 12 votes per user should be sufficient".

I don't necessarily agree with that, but I can see where he is coming from.

One thing I have thought of was allowing the number of close votes for the day to increase based on your rep. Say every 1000 rep you get an extra X votes per day.

Example:

- 3000: 12 votes
- 4000: 15 votes
- 5000: 18 votes
- 6000: 21 votes
- 7000: 24 votes
- 8000: 27 votes
- 9000: 30 votes

So on and so forth (Perhaps have a cap after you hit the 10K rep).

Comment: I can understand Jeff's sentiment. However, I think the team should measure the number of users who are closing, as well as the number of questions that linger with only one or two close votes. It might be interesting.

Comment: I would imagine that the number of users who regularly spend more than half of their close votes is still very low. Most people just are not going to be as interested in policing the site as some users.

Comment: Hence, the reason for increasing the limit for those special few...