# Should we raise the daily cap for close votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

Currently, users can only review 40 close votes a day. But over my last 2 months reviewing there has been an average of 50k + close votes to be reviewed per day!! I propose that we raise the close vote cap to 60, or even to 75. Of course not all users will bother reviewing that many but it'd be good to have the option to get through those extra few.

What do you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase close votes in /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171492/increase-close-votes-in-review), [Should the Daily Close Limit be Higher?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5981/should-the-daily-close-limit-be-higher?rq=1) and a whole bunch of others

Comment: I don' think it's necessary. We should just [use the allocation more efficiently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166217/let-me-choose-when-i-use-my-close-votes) </shamesless plug>.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - I almost linked to yours as well; I still love that proposal

Comment: really nice request. I for one could handle 100 CVs with ease, about 200 would be tough but doable :)

Comment: Looks like they are listening this time... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit/195355?noredirect=1#comment616107_195355

Comment: @Sergio about time too! :)

Comment: I totally agree. I'm tired of all my should be closed flags aging away.