# Increase review quota for very long queues

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

I understand perfectly well why the review quotas are implemented - this question is not about that.  This quota works quite well, however I'm thinking that for very long queues this quota may be temporarily increased to get the queue to a manageable size quicker.

For example, there are presently over 121K questions in the "close vote" queue.  Would it make sense to have some sort of tiered quota, for example, if the queue length is below 10K, then 20 votes per day; for queue length 10K to 50K set the quota to 50 per day - and so on.  I'm not suggesting these particular numbers, just illustrating the idea.

Sometimes, I do have extra time on my hands and would be willing to spend more time cleaning up the content - but the existing quota gives me limited ability to do so.

Comment: this has been raised many time. Analysis of review behavior shows almost no-one reaches their limit anyway; raising the limit won't help. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218541/147247 for example

Comment: You're welcome to join the weekly [close vote event](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) or drop a message if you're reviewing/need support. And bring everybody you know...

Comment: As a 10k user, you can look at the history of all reviews.  Using that ability you can find more questions to close (even if you aren't doing a 'review' for them).

Comment: ^or if you're not 10k just skip through 10 opening them in new tabs before you cap.

Answer (score 8):

This is implemented and is configurable per site. The network default is 1000 items in a queue and surpassing this doubles the reviews allowed per day. In addition, the First Questions queue has a separate setting that allows the reviews per day to be scaled at a different rate, the default of which is three times (tripled).

On Stack Overflow, these have been further configured as noted:

- You can do [**40** reviews per day in a queue if its size is bigger than 150](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/4751173)
- The daily limit for the new First Questions queue is [currently (October 2021) **60**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412063/4751173).

Comment: Sorry for the edits - I've been poking around and this is actually the current configurations - I'll update Yaakov's post.

Comment: This is the first time I see somebody apologizing for drastically improving my post. Thanks a lot @Catija!